# Transferring aliases from Sql Server Configuration manager between machines

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm configuring a consolidated server with named instances and non standard ports.

The only way to allow connectivity is to set up an alias using Sql Server configuration manager. Is there an easy way to move these aliases between machines?

mark

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can export/import these aliases within the registry (insert standard cautionary warning about modifying the registry here).

The keys are found here: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo

Navigate to that location in regedit and use the File -> Export... menu option to export the branch to a .REG file. Then copy that file to the new machine and use File -> Import... to load the keys you just exported into the new machine's registry.

Comment: On x64 there is also a seperate key for 32-bit apps: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo.

Comment: For me (June 2020, SQL 2017), @JoeStefanelli 's  regex key holds the 64bit entries, and VladV's key holds the 32 bit entries